# aac+ streaming issue on KitKat (Android 4.4)

Tags: android, live-streaming, android-4.4-kitkat, aac+

If anyone can help me to fix up  aac+ streaming issue on KitKat (Android 4.4).

Here is the error.

```
11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): playAsync(): 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): java.lang.NullPointerException 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.dumpHeaders(AACPlayer.java:510) 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471) at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.processHeaders(AACPlayer.java:497) 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer.processHeaders(MultiPlayer.java:108) 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:280) 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:248) 11-21 23:30:36.573: E/AACPlayer(1471): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Share some code to understand your error.